# MD5 byte arrays not the same

Tags: c#, md5

So, I've got a text file being stored in a binary(16) field which has been converted into an MD5 hash using the following code:

```
public static byte[] GetHash(string inputString)
{
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = MD5.Create(); // SHA1.Create()
    return algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
}
```

Ok, so for demonstration purposes this hash is 12345678 - I insert this into the database, then proces exactly the same file. Again, create the same byte array of 12345678, confirmed by selecting the hash field from the database using:

```
SELECT HashValue from table
```

this return 12345678 twice, which is fine.

However, when I store this hash value in a byte[] in c# it's completely different

Any reason why, as the sql statement i have in c# returns 12345678 (as viewed in  SQL trace)

### UPDATE

Ok, after @jakebower, I created this method and pass both current hash generated by c# and the one being retrieved from SQL and both strings are the same.

```
public static string GetHashString(string inputString)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var b in GetHash(inputString))
        sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Will checking these two values be a legitimate test to ensure the values are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you retrieving the data from the database?  My guess is that your database is encoding the data (probably ASCII or UTF8) and so when you retrieve the data and shove it in your byte[], it looks "messed up".  You would need to decode it again.

The easiest way to check this would be to shove the value into a string and print the string.  If it looks correct then, this is your answer.

Following your update -- that solution would definitely work.

It would be better form, however, to keep the byte[] returned by the GetHash function.  Then you would want to figure out how your database driver is encoding the data and reversing it to get the byte[] back.

It depends on how maintainable this code needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Checking which two values?

Short answer - probably not.

Your question doesn't explain how the hash is inserted in the database. I can't even make a good guess, because you say "for demonstration purposes this hash is 12345678" and if your hash is a byte array, then it's impossible. Max value for a single byte is 255, if you're combining bytes, I have no idea in which order you are doing it. Furthermore, I have no idea what you're actually storing in the database. Are you storing a string, do you have some other function to store a byte array?

This is what you should do.

1. Use your GetHashString() function to generate the string that you store in the database.
2. Use your GetHashString() function to generate strings you test against the ones in the database.

Now, since all hash strings are generated by the same function, you can be sure that if any two don't match, it is for one of these reasons:

1. Source data has changed.
2. Someone changed the hash string in the database
3. Someone changed your GetHashString() function.

Assuming good practices, 2 and 3 should be highly unlikely to happen without you knowing.